# Active state for state which contains

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have some $states:

```
.state('app.teamsIndex', {url: '/teams'})
.state('app.teamsDetail', {url: '/teams/:id/view'})
.state('app.teamsEdit', {url: '/teams/:id/edit'})
.state('app.teamsCreate', {url: '/teams/create'})
```

When I have `<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.teamsIndex">Teams</a></li>` in my layout the `ui-sref-active` will only trigger on the `app.teamsIndex` but not on the others (`app.teamsDetail` etc.).

I have a navigation with "Teams" which I want to give an active state when I'm on a $state that has something to do with "Teams".

How would I be able to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to create abstract state that parents all of these and then use it with ui-sref-active? Or just make everything a child of index state.

Comment: I did try to create a `app.teams` abstract state with `app.teams.index` as child but then the view is not rendered correctly for some reason.

Comment: What are your trying to do? You are clicking on a link that activates the apps.teamsIndex state, in what way do you want it to activate the rest? Is teamsIndex a page with three sub-views where you want to load details, edit and create views?

Comment: Or do you mean that the corresponding links for the others won't work? Like  ui-sref="app.teamsEdit"?

Comment: @ErikHonn I have a navigation with "Teams" which I want to give a `active` class when I'm on a state which has something to do with teams.

Comment: @guidsen You need to re-visit the approach where `app.teams` is the parent abstract state, and `app.teams.index` the child. The problem you had w/the view not rendering was likely that you just needed an extra `ui-view` in the template b/c of the new state hierarchy you created.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Yes, I think Sunil D has the gist of it. It is not working because states don't care about urls at all, only the state inheritance matters. So to let it know that index is supposed to act as the parent of the rest it literally has to be the parent for the states.